# useEffect conditional statement are not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Here I am making a shopping app and I have a working cart in it and below is my code for my cart component and here in cart I want to render **order** button conditionally for that I have **isFound** state and first I am getting data from my redux store and then I am checking below in useEffect hook if my list is not empty(list is const where I am storing my redux fetched data) then I will set my state=true and initially it is false but the problem is that useEffect is chanigng state to true if there is nothing inside of my list const means even if cart is empty and even though I am setting useEfect dependency proprly as well but it is showing **order** button all the time so someone can please help thanks:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import classes from "./Cart.module.css";

const Cart = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isFound, setIsFound] = useState(false);
  const orders = useSelector((state) => state.data.DUMMY_DATA);

  const list = orders.map(
    (data, key) =>
      data.product_count > 0 && (
        <div className={classes.wrapper}>
          <div className={classes.item}>
            Item: &emsp;&emsp;{data.product_name}{" "}
          </div>
          <div className={classes.amount}>
            Amount:&emsp;&emsp; {data.product_count}{" "}
          </div>
          <div className={classes.price}>
            Price:&emsp;&emsp; {data.product_price}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (list !== "") {
      setIsFound(true);
    }
  }, [list]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.modal}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <span
          className={classes.close}
          onClick={() => navigate("/", { replace: true })}
        >
          &times;
        </span>
        {list}
        {isFound && (
          <div className={classes.order_button_wrapper}>
            <button className={classes.order_button}>Order</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 0):

.map alway return an array. So `list !== ""` will alway be true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is useEffect, you have an array not a string as list value:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (list.length > 0) {
      setIsFound(true);
    }
  }, [list]);
```

Comment: Sir I have added above mentioned solution but it didnt work

Comment: I tried to console orderedList in the console it is storing three indexes with false values like: 0 : false 1 : false 2 : false length : 3

Comment: Thats why condition of useEffect is still becoming true so how am I supposed to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

You have placed a watcher on the `list` variable, that's why `useEffect` is not calling, you need to place a watcher on the `state` because the `state` is being rendered and when any changes to the `state` `useEffect` will be called, variable is not rendered That's is why `useEffect` is not being called and changes to your component are not being replicated. You have to create a `state` and put the `list` value in the state and you have to call the function in the `useEffect` because you only have one called otherwise your function will be calling, as you code below can see.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import classes from "./Cart.module.css";

const Cart = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isFound, setIsFound] = useState(false);
  const orders = useSelector((state) => state.data.DUMMY_DATA);
  const [ordersList, setOrdersList] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const list = orders.map(
      (data, key) =>
        data.product_count > 0 && (
          <div className={classes.wrapper}>
            <div className={classes.item}>
              Item: &emsp;&emsp;{data.product_name}{" "}
            </div>
            <div className={classes.amount}>
              Amount:&emsp;&emsp; {data.product_count}{" "}
            </div>
            <div className={classes.price}>
              Price:&emsp;&emsp; {data.product_price}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    );
    setOrdersList(list);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ordersList !== "") {
      setIsFound(true);
    }
  }, [ordersList]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.modal}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <span
          className={classes.close}
          onClick={() => navigate("/", { replace: true })}
        >
          &times;
        </span>
        {ordersList}
        {isFound && (
          <div className={classes.order_button_wrapper}>
            <button className={classes.order_button}>Order</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Comment: Sadly to inform I copied your code exactly but it is still not working means it useEffect is again setting state to true so it means order button is again visible all the time even when state is empty

Comment: I tried to console orderedList in the console it is storing three indexes with false values like:  0
: 
false
1
: 
false
2
: 
false
length
: 
3

Comment: Thats why condition of useEffect is still becoming true so how am I supposed to deal with this